# Angular server side validation with change event of input

Tags: angularjs

I have searched for topics serverside validation but every solution is done only on submit button. How to do it from input change? if we can add function or directive on the input then how to validate the whole form when input is valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing server side validation for each input is performance issue, there will be lot of request fired to server depends on your form size , thats why most commonly they using server side validation on submit button.

But if you need to do server side validation for each input , I would suggest you to do **Client side validation on ngKeyUp and server side validation on ngBlur** .

AngularJs have built in validations as bellow

```
<input
  ng-model="user.name"
  [name=""]
  [required=""]
  [ng-required=""]
  [ng-minlength=""]
  [ng-maxlength=""]
  [ng-pattern=""]
  [ng-change=""]
  [ng-trim=""]>
...
</input>
```

it sets the Error properties accordingly

```
<tt>myForm.userName.$valid = {{myForm.userName.$valid}}</tt><br>
<tt>myForm.userName.$error = {{myForm.userName.$error}}</tt><br>
<tt>myForm.$valid = {{myForm.$valid}}</tt><br>
<tt>myForm.$error.required = {{!!myForm.$error.required}}</tt><br>
<tt>myForm.$error.minlength = {{!!myForm.$error.minlength}}</tt><br>
<tt>myForm.$error.maxlength = {{!!myForm.$error.maxlength}}</tt><br>
```

So if "myForm.$valid" is true ,then you can trigger a backend validation.

If that clarifies you question?